# how to alert value of hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have code like this.

```
<div class="gridbox">
                    <div class="friend cell">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="name">Bob</span>
                            <br />
                            (id: 57)
                            <input type="hidden" class="friend_id" value="57 " />
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

I want to alert value of hidden field.
I have many items like this. Not just this one.
all have different ids and when clicking on particular div it should alert its id.

Comment: 2 seconds for me ;) http://bit.ly/Pfjwmn

Comment: Nice work @Michal Klouda...how can i get that type of works

Comment: @Gautam3164: It is quite difficult: http://bit.ly/vXtvlP :P

Comment: Thanks dude,by this small question,i foun some great thing.its funny too,

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want:

```
$('.friend').on('click', function() {
    var friend_id = $('.friend_id', this).val();
    alert(friend_id);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/wp748/

Comment: I am having a problem.
Its showing an error that this method is not supported.
So i used only click.
But it alerts 2 times.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: In that case, simply switch `on()` for `bind()`. http://jsfiddle.net/aymansafadi/wp748/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should put an id on your hidden field, or grab it using the class:

```
alert($(".friend_id").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
alert($("input:hidden").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

like a javascript alert?  I would use jquery.

alert($('.friend_id').val());

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try like

```
alert($("input:hidden[class='friend_id']").val());
```

or

```
alert($("input:hidden .friend_id").val());
```